# como faço para pegar um texto dentro de um input com selenium python

Tags: html, python, input, selenium-webdriver

tem um site que da emails temporarios e esse site mostra o email dentro de uma caixa input,
e eu nao consigo retirar o email dentro dessa caixa, procurei pelo email dentro do html e percebi que ele nem manda o email para o codigo htlm, tem alguma forma de eu conseguir obter esse email?

obs: o email aparece na tela mas não no codigo.

o input esta assim:

Answer (score -1):

Se o elemento aparece na tela ele existe em algum lugar.

Procure pelo email nas requisições da página (inspecionar elemento -> Network)

Utilize o [selenium-wire](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/) para chegar até estas requisições dentro do seu código.

Comment: foi bem isso mano, conseguir achar o email nas propriedades do elemento, mas foi uma experiência bem louca eu não imaginava que poderia ter algo na tela sem esta codificado no html